# Updating the GUI from a TimerTask using Handler

Tags: java, android, timer

Globally, I have a the following:

`Timer timer = new Timer();`

in my onResume() I have the following code.

`timer.schedule(new syncTimerTask(), 1, 30000);`

and my syncTimerTask is as follows :

```
class syncOutgoingUpdatesTimerTask extends TimerTask
{
    public void run()
    {
    //some sync process with outer back end server
    //fetch results etc

     myHandler.post(myRunnable);
    }
}
```

my handler and runnable are declared globally as follows

```
final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable()
{
   public void run() 
   {
        //update GUI, text views whatever.
   }
};
```

And inside my onPause() I call `timer.cancel();`

The above code is neat, straight to the point and does the job perfectly.
But in order to grasp the idea better, I have some concerns and questions.

1. Assume the syncing too a lot of time, and the user pressed the back button. This will cause the onPause to get caused , which will stop the timer from repeating itself, however the running TimerTask will continue running. But what happens when the code reaches the line of `myHandler.post(myRunnable);` where the handler calls the runnable, but there is no GUI to update ? Do I get a null pointer there ?
2. Assume the sync started and again it took a lot of time, in which state, the user pressed the home button and got out of the app and removed the app from the 'recent apps' which 'kills' the app, calling onDestroy() on all methods. In this case, does the thread of the timer (which is a seperate thread and not the UI thread, stops wherever it is, (even though it might be in the middle) because it is associated with the app ?), assume this is true, the code won't even reach the `myHandler.post(myRunnable);` so no null pointers will occur.. is this the case ?

Comment: use `runOnUIThread` and why not just handler if you want to repeat some task

Comment: @Raghunandan runOnUIThread has caused me issues at times. and I cannot use just handler because I am doing network tasks. The handler will run on the UI thread (because I am creating it there)..

Comment: why not use asynctask it is easier to use

Comment: so use HandlerThread instead of Timer/TimerTask stuff

Comment: @Raghunandan `AsyncTask` is not the tool for this, and would have the same potential problems.

Comment: @pskink handler thread suits the case better than Timers() ?? I honestly have no experience HandlerThreads, some advice would not harm :)

Comment: @Darkhogg `HandlerThread` is a good options as pskink suggested

Comment: HandlerThread is used frequently in android sdk sources, Tiner is not so i think the devs know what they are doing

Comment: @pskink indeed. Let me dig a deeper into HandlerThread, and I'll come with a conclusion and point it out here.. thanks a lot for the info !

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the event will run, and if you nullify things out it might cause problems. The best you can do is to have a flag that tells you, from your `Runnable`, that the activity is paused.
2. No, the app is not *killed*, just stopped (unless the Android process manager kills it for memory as usual). In this case your timer thread continues running and executes the `Runnable` in the main thread, with the same potential problems of 1.

Comment: for 1 - I think a nice approach would be creating a global boolean value `boolean activityIsRunning;` and setting it to true inside onResume() and false inside onPause() and do something like `if(activityIsRunning) { //run handler } no ? ----

for 2 - have a look hear, the link suggestes that the app is inface killed rather than stopped. unsure tho.

Comment: For 1, yes, that's it.
For 2, unless the process manager decides *immediately* after stopping activities that it has to kill your app, it will still run. But that's something you have to assume with Android from the very beggining.

Comment: regarding 1, does it help to consider using weakReference ? or the above approach would be more than enough ?

Comment: No, don't use weak references unless you have a *really* good reason for it. Just have the `if` setup like you said and everything should work.